# How can I disable work php files in a specific directory in My site

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I have folder containing several files and sub-folders such as the following:

```
-/folder
    -/subfolder
    -/subfolder
    -/subfolder
    -/etc...
-index.html
-control.php
-ads.php
-/etc...
```

Now I want to disable work PHP or other files in main directory only (-/folder) like (-index.html, -control.php) , but all sub-folder files I want to works well.

I want to have effect on the files within that main folder only .

Comment: Disable PHP? So any PHP file in that directory is served as the source code? Why? What is your real-life situation, why do you need this?

Comment: disable how? prevent them from being viewed? executed? not treat them as php files?

Comment: -1 for not improving the question despite being asked repeatedly to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need a .htaccess in the given directory with this content:

```
deny from all
```

Edit: Since as far as I know .htaccess rules apply to all subdirectories as well, you might have to create a .htaccess file in each subdir to override the restriction specified for root

```
allow from all
```

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to
>   the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all
>   subdirectories thereof.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#how

Comment: This will affect all sub-directories as well

Comment: @salla: I want main folder files only , but sub-folder files work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, you can add to your virtual-host the

```
<directory /path/to/dir>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from All
</directory>
```

directive **for each sub-directories**, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

(I hope I understand your need)

**Edit**
if you need to filter files instead of directories, you can use a glob matching like that

```
<Files *.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from All
</Files>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#files

Comment: This will affect all sub-directories as well

Comment: @sputnick: I want main folder files only , but sub-folder files work fine

Comment: unfortunately, disable work with main and sub directory files , but I want to disable work with main directory files only

Comment: @sputnick: This will apply to all files in main and sub directory, and I want only apply to all files in the main directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple  directives to override the first directive

```
<directory /path/to/dir>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</directory>

<directory /path/to/dir/subdir>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</directory>
```

Comment: unfortunately, disable work with main and sub directory files , but I want to disable work with main directory files only